# Making sure a test function has been called before calling an other function

Tags: c#, oop

Good morning / afternoon / evening,

I will directly dive into an example to illustrate my problem.

Let's take two simples (C#) classes : `Bag` and `Item`.

```
public class Bag
{
    public bool CanAddItem( Item item, float value, out Vector positionInBag )
    {
        // Do heavy calculation
        // Returns true if the item can be added into the bag
        // False otherwise
    }

    public void AddItem( Item item, Vector position )
    {
        // Add the item into the bag at the specified position
    }
}

public class Item
{
    Vector positionInBag ;

    public void PresentToBag( Bag bag, float value )
    {
        if( bag.CanAddItem( this, value, out positionInBag ) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I can be added " + positionInBag ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I can't be added!" ) ;
        }
    }

    public void DropIntoBag( Bag bag )
    {
        bag.AddItem( this, positionInBag  ) ;
    }
}
```

My problem is the following: **How can I make sure the `Item.DropIntoBag` function is called with the absolute certainty it can be added to the bag**?

### 1st possible solution

I could just call `if( bag.CanAddItem(this) )`  before calling `bag.AddItem` but:

- `bag.CanAddItem` does heavy calculation, and `Item.PresentToBag` function is supposed to be called right before calling `DropIntoBag`, thus, `bag.CanAddItem` is supposed to be already called.
- `bag.CanAddItem` returns (using the `out` keyword) important data for the `Item` in order to do be added to the correct place

### 2nd possible solution

I could add a boolean inside the `Item` class indicating whether the item can be added to the bag. But the value could be manipulated by the item itself, which is could lead to a wrong output.

### 3rd possible solution

I could add a map  inside the `Bag` class indicating whether the item can be added to the bag (thus, avoiding the heavy computation). But, because `Bag.CanAddItem` relies on a value which does not belong to the Item class, I don't think i can do this way.

---

After calling `Item.DropIntoBag`, the item is supposed to be correctly in the bag (and the `positionInBag` is supposed to be a valid position in the bag), but I don't see how to guarantee it. Maybe with Exceptions? But it would imply to make the heavy computation to test whether the item can be added.

---

Thanks in advance for your advices. I hope this question is not too opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions (not best, but with minimal changes in existed code):

```
public class Bag
{
    public bool CanAddItem( Item item, float value, out Vector positionInBag )
    {
        // Do heavy calculation
        // Returns true if the item can be added into the bag
        // False otherwise
    }

    public void AddItem( Item item, Vector position )
    {
        // Add the item into the bag at the specified position
    }
}

public interface ICanBeDropped{
    public void Drop();
}

public class DropIntoBagHolder: ICanBeDropped{
    Item item;
    float amount;
    Bag bag;
    Vector positionInBag ;

    DropIntoBagHolder(...){ ... }

    public void Drop(){
        bag.AddItem( item, value maybe here?, positionInBag  ) ;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public ICanBeDropped PresentToBag( Bag bag, float value )
    {
        Vector positionInBag ;
        if( bag.CanAddItem( this, value, out positionInBag ) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I can be added " + positionInBag ) ;
            return new DropIntoBagHolder(....);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("I can't be added!" ) ;
        return null; // will cause exception
    }
}
```

---

i think that all design is kinda strange. Why items know about bag? Maybe you could create some higher-level object that will represent interaction between `Bag` and (current) `Item`?

Comment: Interesting solution! If I understand correctly, an item could not be dropped in the bag anymore, but a "temporary object" you get only if you have checked the item can be dropped?

Comment: Yes, it may, instead of null, return some DummyPlacer with custom behavior